# ffmpeg returning nonsense

Tags: console, ffmpeg, cmd

I use this command

```
ffmpeg -i X.mpg -b 533k –vcodec h263 -ac 1 -ab 48k -acodec aac -strict experimental -s 352x288 X.3gp
```

from cmd to convert file X from mpg to 3gp. I even used this yesterday and it worked.
Today I decided to improve the command:

```
ffmpeg –i X.mpg -b 1000k –r 25 –vcodec h263 -ac 1 -ab 15750 –ar 8000 -acodec libopencore_amrnb -s 352x288 X.3gp
```

Now ffmpeg is completely screwed up, it returns garbage like

```
[NULL @ 02EFF020] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ÔÇôvcodec'
ÔÇôvcodec: Invalid argument
```

or

```
[NULL @ 02CBEA80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ÔÇôi'
ÔÇôi: Invalid argument
```

even if I use the first command, which it worked and now, on the same file, in the same directory, with a new fresh ffmpeg executable from the same archive I extracted it before, it doesn't convert anymore.
If I type a nonexistent file as input, ffmpeg gives

```
[NULL @ 02CBEA80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ÔÇôr'
ÔÇôr: Invalid argument
```

I really don't know what to do. Looks like something really basic has been changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash in `–vcodec` option is the wrong character (code 0x96, should be 0x2D). Delete and retype. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Fixed! There was an error on arguments 'r', 'vcodec', 'i', 'ar' because I copied the script in Word. To ensure it was not a formatting issue I usually copy from Word to Notepad, but this time it didn't work.